# How to sort the dict of words based on the alphabet order

Tags: python

I have some problems with this exercise:
Create a function named countWords_1() that takes two file names as the inputs. The
first one is the input file’s name (a text file) and the second one is the output file’s name
(a JSON file). The function will count the number of times the words in the input text
file occur then write the result (in JSON format) into the output file and do the following:

- Calculate the words’ frequency in percentage (with two digits in the decimal
  places)
- Sort the list of words based on the frequency value, from highest to lowest. Any
  words that have equal frequency values will be arranged in alphabetical order.
- Save the result to the output file in JSON format.
  [The input and output of this excercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ugjc.png)

I have finished calculating the word's frequency in percentage and sorted the list of words based on the frequency value, from highest to lowest but I don't know how to arrange the words that have equal frequency values in alphabet order. And my code has the correct JSON format, doesn't it?

```
import os
import json
```

def countWords_1(file1, file2):
percentage_frequency = {}  #result that will be written into the file

```
with open(file1) as data:
    f = data.read().lower()  # convert all strings in file1 to lowercase

# modify the file: Delete blank lines, duplicated spaces
file_without_blanklines = f.replace("\n", " ")  # delete blank lines
file_stripped = file_without_blanklines.strip()

file_modified = " ".join(file_stripped.split())
wordList = file_modified.split(" ")

# save keys and value into created dict
for word in wordList:
    count_word = wordList.count(word)
    percentage = round((count_word/len(wordList))*100, 2)
    # create key-value pairs in dict percentage_frequency
    percentage_frequency[word] = percentage

# sort of the dict
# based on frequency value
sorted_wordList = {}
sortedValue = sorted(percentage_frequency.values(), reverse=True)
for sortedKey in sortedValue:
    for key, value in percentage_frequency.items():
        if value == sortedKey:
            sorted_wordList[key] = value
```

Comment: Can you make a simple working code and expected output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the tupples (-value, word), for example:

```
d = {'hello': 123, 'how': 11, 'are': 123, 'you': 12, 'today': 12}

[(w, -v) for v, w in sorted([(-v, w) for w, v in d.items()])]
```

Output:

```
[('are', 123), ('hello', 123), ('today', 12), ('you', 12), ('how', 11)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-by-step approach with explanations in comments:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

INFILE = 'sample.txt'
OUTFILE = 'sample.json'

words = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

# build a dictionary keyed by unique words and with a value representing the number of occurrences of that word
with open(INFILE) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for w in line.strip().lower().split():
            words[w] += 1
# count total number of words
wordcount = sum(words.values())
# build a dictionary keyed by unique words and a value representing the percentage
#   of its occurrences compared with the total number of words
jtemp = {k: round(v / wordcount * 100.0, 2) for k, v in words.items()}
# build a list of tuples (percentage, word) so that we can sort on the percentage
#  then build the final output dictionary with values in the required order
jout = {k: v for v, k in sorted([(v_, k_) for k_, v_ in jtemp.items()], reverse=True)}
# dump the dictionary as JSON to the output file
with open(OUTFILE, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(jout, indent=4))
```